# Google App Engine: Issue with app.yaml file

Tags: html, google-app-engine, localhost

I am trying to publish my HTML based website to my Google App Engine service. I am not using any PHP code for this project since it's just a landing page.

**This is my project structure:**

[image]

And I believe I need a app.yaml file to publish to GAE? **Here's my app.yaml file:**

```
application: earthling-app
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
```

However, when I run my application in Google App Engine Launcher, this is what it shows:

[image]

I get a "The url "/index.html" does not match any handlers.", 'Not Found' error.

Is my structure and app.yaml correct and safe to be published to the GAE Service? Why am I not seeing my site properly?

**EDIT**

After Amber's suggestion, this is my app.yaml:

```
application: earthling-app
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_dir: static
```

And I moved all my static files to a folder named 'static'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 handlers defined: `/js`, `/images`, and `/css`. None of those match `/index.html`, so when you try to visit the path including `/index.html`, the application throws an error because it doesn't know what to do.

You need to define one or more handlers that match the actual pages you want to serve, not just the js/images/css paths.

For a completely static website like yours, the simplest way would probably be to only define a single handler:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  static_dir: static
```

And then put your entire website (include css/images/js) inside the `static` directory:

```
earthling/
  app.yaml
  static/
    css/
      ...
    images/
      ...
    js/
      ...
    index.html
    favicon.ico
    ...
```

If you do it this way, you don't even need any python files, because the entire website will be served on a file-by-file basis by the static_dir rule (`/.*` matches any path, since `.*` matches any string).

Comment: Can you show me what to add to my app.yaml please? I am kinda new to this :)

Comment: Hm I still get 'The url "/" does not match any handlers.' when I tried 'http://localhost:8084/'. I also tried 'http://localhost:8084/index.html' still no luck.

Comment: Oh the URL 'http://localhost:8084/static/index.html' loaded the page. But the CSS and JS were not loaded

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would serve your site using [Google Clould Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration). It's got a feature to serve static web sites. It works as a CDN, and you will only pay for the data transferred.